Error while creating a Jss Tenant in Sitecore 10.3.1
I recently installed the Headless rendering package, which is relevant to the Sitecore version I am using: Sitecore 10.3.1.[Sitecore Headless Services Server XM 21.0.587 ]. However, I am unable to create a JSS tenant as the execution stops midway, and the following error is shown in the SPE logs.

19460 14:18:13 INFO [Runner] Executing script {63A133F9-262F-4EF5-9382-09F6AAAFEFE3} for Context User sitecore\Admin as sitecore\Admin.
ManagedPoolThread #5 14:18:13 ERROR Cannot index into a null array.

Please do provide your suggestions on how to resolve this.
